# How to make other function gets called after first is executed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux

I am working on a react app where I am using redux for state management and I have 2 functions to call and I want them to run only after 1st function is executed.

Here's a snippet of whats I am doing:

```
if (this.props.page_num < this.props.numPages) {
       this.props.fetchCode(params, isFiltered, isSearched).then(() => {
          this.props.setPageNumber(this.props.page_num + 1);
        });
      }
```

Here I am getting a error stating:

```
CodeTable.jsx?2468:132 Uncaught TypeError: this.props.fetchCode(...).then is not a function
```

fetchCode function:

```
export function* fetchCode(action) {
  try {
    const response = yield call(Services.fetchCode, action.params);
    const { dtoList } = response.data.pagedList;
    const num_pages = response.data.pagedList.numPages;
    const total_records = response.data.pagedList.totalRecords;
    const page_number = response.data.pagedList.pageNumber;
    const postCodeSetsData = dtoList.map(({
    }) => ({
    }));
    yield put(ActionCreator.setCodes(dtoList, num_pages, total_records, postCodeData, page_number, action.isFiltered, action.isSearched));
  } catch (error) {
    sagaException(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is returned by `this.props.fetchCodeSets(...)`?

Comment: its a redux thing,so fetchCodeSets calls a saga function and sets value in the reducer,doesnt return anything

Comment: So if `this.props.fetchCodeSets(...)` returns nothing, that means `this.props.fetchCodeSets(...).then(...)` is like: `undefined.then(...)`. Unless `this.props.fetchCodeSets(...)` returns a promise or an object with the `then` method, you cannot call `then` on the result of `this.props.fetchCodeSets(...)`

Comment: how to overcome this?

Comment: By not calling `then`?!

Comment: but I want to run setPageNumber function after running fetchCodesets

Comment: I have added the fetchCodeSets function

Comment: how to return a promise from that function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using redux saga, I believe the most appropriate thing to do is compose another saga.

```
export function* fetchCodeSetsAndSetPage(action) {
  try {
    yield put (ActionCreator.fetchCodes(...));
    yield put (ActionCreator.setPageNumber(...));
  } catch (error) {
    sagaException(error);
  }
}
```

And then call that one instead in your component.

Some [docs](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/SequencingSagas/).

Answer (score -1):

make fetchCodeSets function async. You can write promise like then only with an async functions. also use a return statement inside the function. The declaration of the fetchCodeSets function should be like this

```
const fetchCodeSets = async (params) => {
    //codes here
    return;
}
```

Comment: fetchCodeSets is a saga function